# Ajax loader script calls php script twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use ajax on my html page to load data from db w.o. reload and send email notification on some event, its works perfect
and in same time I use function that show and hide ajax loader image, but it calls my php script twice so that each time it sends email twice

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

// ajax loader image

  function getuser(str){
     $.ajax({
      url: "http://site.com/getuser.php?q="+str,
      beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest)
      {
         $("#loading").show();
      }
    }).done(function ( data ) {
     $("#txtHint").html(data);
     $("#loading").hide(); });
  }
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name='users']").change(function () {
   getuser($("option:selected", this).val()); });
   });

</script>
```

how to improve this function to call php script just one time?

Comment: The code you posted should behave correctly. I'm probably missing something, but the problem should be somewhere else. Make sure you don't register a listener twice.

Comment: add code in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function getuser(str){
 $.ajax({
  url: "http://site.com/script.php?q="+str,
  beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest)
  {
     $("#loading").show();
  }
}).done(function ( data ) {
 //     $("#txtHint").html(data);
 $("#loading").hide(); });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select[name='users']").bind('change',function () {
 getuser($("option:selected", this).val()); });
 });
```